# What is %s+ or %s used for in lua and how do you use it?

Tags: string, lua

How do i use %s in lua, or a better question would be how is it used?

so here is what i have tried before assuming this is how it is used and how it works.

```lua
local arg1 = 'lmao'

print('fav string is %arg1')
```

at first i thought it was something used to reference a string or numeral inside of a string without doing like

```lua
print('hello '..name..'!')
```

Can someone provide me some examples or a explanation on how this is used and what for?

Answer (score 5):

A `%` in a string has no meaning in Lua syntax, but does mean something to certain functions in the `string` library.

In `string.format`, `%` is used to make a format specifier that converts another argument to a string. It's documented at [`string.format`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.format), but that refers to [Output Conversion Syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Output-Conversion-Syntax.html#Output-Conversion-Syntax) and [Table of Output Conversions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Table-of-Output-Conversions.html#Table-of-Output-Conversions) to explain almost all of the specifier syntax.

The `%` is also used to designate a character class in the [pattern syntax](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1) used with some `string` functions.

Here is your code using `string.format`:

```
local arg1 = 'lmao'
print(string.format('fav string is %s', arg1))
```

Or, taking advantage of the string metatable:

```
local arg1 = 'lmao'
print(('fav string is %s'):format(arg1))
```

Answer (score 3):

Lua uses `%s` in patterns (Lua's version of regular expressions) to mean "whitespace". `%s+` means "one or more whitespace characters".

Ref: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1